# Selenium Actions.click() with no wait Java Chromedriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing a selenium script that interacts with one of our systems. In our system, there is a button that, when pressed, only loads the page correctly about half the time (It just hangs on loading for an infinite amount of time on every other occasion) and therefore I cannot rely on the default selenium wait for the page to load. For this reason, I would like to press the button, and close the web browser immediately before opening up a new window to continue on with the script. Unfortunately I have no ability to fix the issue with the button itself.

My current code:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.id("garbage_button"));
        
action.moveToElement(webElement).click();
        
action.perform();

System.out.println("It's worked");
```

Currently, the System.out will unlikely be reached because once the action.perform() is run the page just infinitely hangs and my script eventually times out.

Other things I have tried:

- WebElement.click() instead
- Reducing the wait time and attempting to
  catch the time out exception (Chromedriver seems to handle these
  exceptions itself)

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could achieve a button press without any wait?

Comment: The page is hanging after you clicked on button and not able to close the browser. You want to close the browser but no code is being executed after browser hangs so explicitly you want to close the browser. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I'm able to shut the browser correctly by closing the driver and opening a new one. This code is working so I didn't feel the need to include it.

Answer (score 1):

`action.perform();` should be `action.build().perform();` in Java.

Once you do that why not to trigger `driver.quit()`  to close the windows  ?

or you can possibly have an assert when the click in triggered, you could assert something from next page and if assertion pass then test case should pass as well.

But since you've mentioned many times new page won't load, in those situation your assertion will fail, and that should be okay cause actual page did not load at all.

Comment: Thank you for the correction! The problem is, the code still hangs on the action.build().perform() because it doesn't progress from that line until the page has loaded so I can't close the window and I can't run an assert directly after it.

Comment: No while writing the assert think about positive outcome which will be to have something on the new page for example page title, assert new page title. If new page does not come up, assert would fail, and that's the expected behavior.

Comment: Do you think you could provide some rough syntax on what you mean? If I place an assert directly after the build().perform() (For example Assert.assertEquals(true, elementOnNextPage.isDisplayed()); it will never reach that line. Just trying to understand what you mean. Thanks again for your help

Comment: When click occurs successfully, do you see any change in page title ?

Comment: No - the only thing that changes is the entire page becomes disabled (grayed out) and a waitforresponse.gif (A loading icon) is displayed in the middle of the page

Comment: I was referring when the click is successful ? there should be some heading, something to verify right  ?

Comment: I'm not amazing with web dev - could you elaborate on what I might be looking for ?

Comment: `build()` is already included in `perform()` https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/702b3aae7385adf331d75cdeacd79720cf6b9c84/java/src/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.java

Comment: Well it depends see here `Generates a composite action containing all actions so far, ready to be performed (and
   * resets the internal builder state, so subsequent calls to this method will contain fresh
   * sequences`. But yes perform should be able to handle in this case.

Answer (score 0):

> In our system, there is a button that, when pressed, only loads the
> page correctly about half the time (It just hangs on loading for an
> infinite amount of time on every other occasion) and therefore I
> cannot rely on the default selenium wait for the page to load.

You can load the page faster by doing this. This will make Selenium WebDriver to wait until the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, and discards loading of stylesheets, images and subframes.

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.EAGER);
```

You can kill driver session by using below command.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM ChromeDriver.exe");
```